# Kali Linux will not boot from USB, terminal asks for kernel image

Tags: linux, boot, usb, kernel

I have been trying to boot Kali Linux from a USB.

I have turned the USB bootable with the newest 64 bit Kali ISO and Universal USB Creator or whatever it was called, and it seems to have worked just fine; however, now everytime I try to boot the USB I catch a small glimpse of what I guess is Kali's introduction/copyright text, then instantaneously replaced by a terminal-like black screen with the only word in it being "boot:" and an intermittent hyphen prompting me to write something.

Whatever I write, all it says in return is "Could not find kernel image: [thing I wrote]" and makes another "boot:" appear, in hope that I be able to write something of use.

I have checked around the internet but all I have found were people complaining about the boot automatically saying "Could not find kernel image: linux", which is not exactly my case. Do I have to edit the syslinux.cfg to redirect it to the kernel like in those other cases? If so, what do I have to write? All I've found are people telling other victims to do so but without really telling them what to write in the .cfg.

I await someone's kind response, thanks. BTW, I have tried this both in my Windows 8 laptop and in my Windows 7 desktop computer, to the same result.

Answer (score 0):

One of three reasons/awnser I have for you:

- It (somehow) finds the kernel then it does not knows where it is
- Your Bootable USB software does not work right
- The USB files got corrupted ???

Anyway first thing would be to find the file name of the kernel on a working OS then boot it and type in that file name (with extension). If that does not work format the drive and reinstall your installer, then if that does not work maybe try a new extraction software ???